# Sizeof of derived class with virtual destructor

Tags: c++

During job interview, I've been overwhelmed by this question:

bool Res - what it shows to us?

```
template <class T>
class R
{
        class A: public T {
                virtual ~A(){}
        };
public:
        static const bool Res = sizeof(A) == sizeof(T);
};
```

During my investigation - I've always had sizeof(T) == 1, while sizeof(A) varies. Explanation will be very appreciated.

Comment: Try adding a virtual function to `T`.

Comment: `sizeof(r)` isn't interesting. What's `sizeof R<base>::A`?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it has no place in a job interview. Some software-development companies are really out of their mind.

Comment: @Christian That depends in part on how the answers are assessed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value of `Res` should indicate whether `T` has any `virtual` function although there is no such guarantee in the C++ standard:

- If `T` does have a `virtual` function, `A` doesn't add anything to the representation and *can* be the same size as `T`.
- If `T` does not have a `virtual` function, `A` *probably* adds something to deal with the dynamic dispatch (typically a pointer to something like a `virtual` function pointer table) and has a different size.

The C++ standard doesn't mandate how to dynamic dispatch is implemented and an implementation *could* be able to some determine from the address what type an object has. In practice all implementations do use a pointer to dynamic type information.

An interesting question is whether a compiler could detect that `R<T>::A;` can't be used to be inherited from and, thus, decide that it doesn't actually need a `virtual` function pointer anyway. I'm pretty sure a compiler could do so making the value of `R<T>::Res` even more questionable.

Comment: @Starl1ght: why would you be interested in the size of `R<base>`? You are interested in the value `R<base>::Res` or in `sizeof(R<base>::A)`.

Answer (score 3):

If T is polymorphic class (has virtual destructor or any virtual method), the size should be the same.

If T is not polymorphic (doesn't have any virtual methods), the size of A is bigger by a pointer to virtual function table.

EDIT.
Further explanation: If a class has any virtual method (it means it is designed for being used polymorphically), it has to have a pointer to a virtual function table, which is used to determine which method exactly should be used when a virtual method is called.

Comment: Example here: http://ideone.com/FfGdjo You could mention that it's not guaranteed by the standard that virtual functions are implemented using a vtable. Though in practice this had no relevance.

Comment: @DanielJour you are of course right, thanks. I won't change it because it is already explained better in the accepted answer.